# iPod Touch 5th gen not responding

Tags: ipod-touch

my iPod touch 5th gen will not respond. it is stuck in the FaceTime app frozen and i have my "accessive touch" on the screen and it just keeps flashing on and off. and neither of my buttons work. help me? thanks

Comment: hold the home button for a while.

Comment: my home button is broken :/

Comment: remove and reinstall the battery :/

Comment: how do i do that? where is the battery?

Answer (score 1):

Hold down BOTH the home button and the sleep button until the device shuts off (can take several seconds).  Then you should e able to turn the device back on normally by holding the sleep button for a second.

Comment: good suggestion. but problem is buttons don't work

Comment: I think many of us are now confused.  Are your buttons permanently and physically broken or are they just not working right now because it's Frozen on FaceTime?  If, they are permanently broken then how are you actually using the iPod since there is no way to switch between apps?  If, the buttons are just not working because of the FaceTime freeze, then you should try what I said and hold both buttons at the same time (this WILL shut off the device).

Answer (score 0):

Since all you buttons are not working anymore...

Pardon me for saying it, but it looks like you are not much of a Expert in Electronics devices, to for example remove the battery.

In that case just let the battery drain, and it will shut down by it self.

I would also highly suggest you get those buttons repaired by a professional.